# Xcode not linking two structures?

Tags: c++, xcode, struct

Why is Xcode saying "Vertex.h" not recognized ?

```
//Vertex.h
#include "Edge.h"
struct Vertex 
{
     vector<Edge> adjList;
     string myData;

};
```

In a separate file,

```
//Edge.h
#include "Vertex.h"
struct Edge
{
    Vertex* destination; // "Unknown type named 'Vertex.h'
    double weight;
}
```

Is there a mistake here somewhere ? Please help. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry, what is a guard ? Even Though I didn't include here I have my "ifndef", "def" and "endif"

Answer (score 3):

You have a circular dependency: `Vertex.h` depends on `Edge.h` which depends on `Vertex.h`...

In your specific case it's very easy to solve, as `Edge.h` doesn't need the full definition of `Vertex`, only know that the `Vertex` structure exists, so change it like

```
//Edge.h
struct Vertex;
struct Edge
{
    Vertex* destination; // "Unknown type named 'Vertex.h'
    double weight;
};
```

The change is that you don't include `Vertex.h`, instead you declare the `Vertex` structure. This tells the compiler that a structure named `Vertex` exists, so it can be used for e.g. pointers or references.